# Using Password Vault to Retrieve Encrypted Password for PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

when I run this directly from a PowerShell prompt via Command Prompt Window it successfully retrieves the password.   When I have the Windows Task Scheduler run the script it only works if I hardcode the password versus use the method below to bring in the password.

What am I missing in understanding how Task Scheduler would deal with this code?

```
$vault = 'D:\TEST\figpwd.txt' 
# retrieve the password.
$securestring = convertto-securestring -string (get-content $vault)
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securestring)
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
# connect to DB2 Database.
$factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory('IBM.Data.DB2')
$cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
$cstrbld.Database = 'MYDBNAME'
$cstrbld.UserID = 'myuser'
$cstrbld.Password = $password
$cstrbld.Server = 'myservername:50001'
$dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
$dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
$dbconn.Open()
```

Comment: Assuming the `.txt` file has a encrypted standard string, is the scheduled task __running as the same user that exported the encrypted string__ ?

Comment: Well, from what I can tell, an encrypted string can only be read by the user which exported it and only in the computer where it was exported. See DPAPI for more info.

Comment: yes - it is, I created the powershell code with my AD user account - and the password is for a database user.  How can I run the script as SYSTEM with Task Scheduler?

Comment: If you exported the encrypted string with your user, the task would need to run as your user (which obviously is not recommended). You would need to use a service account, export the credentials using a pwsh session running as that service account and then create the task and set the credentials so the task runs as that service account. Or, use gMSA and forget about all that hassle.

Comment: You could run PowerShell as the SYSTEM user by launching it with PSExec by running `psexec.exe -s -i powershell.exe`. Then encrypt and export the stuff from that session. Then when you run the scheduled task as SYSTEM it will be able to decrypt it.

Comment: It works from the command line but not in Task Scheduler - for it just hangs -  ``` D:\TEST\psexec -s -i "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe" -File "D:\TEST\testrun2.ps1" ```  If I run it from CMD.exe - I have to hit enter to release the session